# How to append every X in c# stringbuilder

Tags: c#, append, stringbuilder

I'm using unity and c# and am not sure how to use stringbuilder to append a "/" every X characters. I have code and can build a string from a array with the code below, and add a comma after each string, but i need to add the "/" after every x string

it should for example convert "122342" to "1,2,2,/,3,4,2". Currently it would convert it to "1,2,2,3,4,2"
this is the code i have already

```
StringBuilder Builtstring = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string griditem in tobuild){

    Builtstring.Append(griditem).Append(",");

}
built = Builtstring.ToString();
```

Comment: added sample output as per request. changed char to string also.

Comment: My answer below will do that - however it will end in a ',' - you will want to remove the last ','

Comment: you just use ToCharArray guys, can do the whole thing in one line

Comment: the key thing here is there is *no reason* to use "StringBuilder" here

Comment: He already has a Char array.. he wants to build a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FOR loop and then check if the character is a factor of some desired nTH character. If so add an extra '/'.

```
        int x = 2; // your x
        StringBuilder builtstring = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < tobuild.Length; i++) 
        { 
            string item = tobuild[i];
            builtstring.Append(item).Append(",");
            if (i%x==0) { builtstring.Append("/"); }

        }
        string built = builtstring.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array of strings using a [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop, which provides an index.
For each iteration, add the current String to the `StringBuilder`, in addition to a ',' in case we still didn't reach the last string in the array.
Also, after x strings add a '/'. We can know that we reached `x` strings using the [% (modulus)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) operator.
Notice that I start the loop from index = 1. I do that because the modulus operator for the value 0 with any positive number will yield 0, which will add the '/' char after the first word, something that we don't necessarily want.

```
static void Insert(StringBuilder b, int x, string[] tobuild)
{
    for(var index = 1; index < tobuild.Length; ++index)
    {   
        b.Append(tobuild[index]);

        if(index != tobuild.Length -1)
        {
            b.Append(",");
        }

        if(0 == index % x)
        {
            b.Append("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement to evaluate the character and then act accordingly.

```
StringBuilder Builtstring = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string griditem in tobuild){
if(griditem == 'x') { Builtstring.Append(griditem).Append(@"/"); }
Builtstring.Append(griditem).Append(",");

}
built = Builtstring.ToString();
```

Or if you actually want to count a certain number of characters before putting a slash you can do this.

```
int count = 10;
int position = 0;
StringBuilder Builtstring = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string griditem in tobuild){
if(position == count) { Builtstring.Append(griditem).Append(@"/"); position = 0; }
else{Builtstring.Append(griditem).Append(","); position++;}}
built = Builtstring.ToString();
```